# Unity Mobile Controller in "2D Game Kit "?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am new in unity . I am making 2D game for fun . I want to make its mobile version as well . I am using [unity 2D game kit](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/2d-game-kit-107098)

I did not found any mobile controller for this pack inside package . Anyone knows way how to make it work for mobile ?

any kind of help is appreciated .

Comment: Can you fix the link in your question? (I would but an edit has been pending for awhile.) As for how to make it work for mobile can you be a bit more specific on what you mean by make it work for mobile?  Are you trying to make the character move on mobile?  How are you trying to make the character move?  Just touching the screen? What buttons do you need? are you going to use swipes or gestures? or a joystick layout?  Do I tap the screen and the character just moves there, and figures out where to jump?

Comment: I suspect you are looking for a visual joystick also known as Cross Platform Input and that's is in the Standard Assets.